# Is there a way to take a screenshot in NativeScript?

Tags: typescript, nativescript

i have a draw pad in front of an image that i would like to screenshot. Is there a possible way to do it with nativescript.

Comment: Hi guys,
Same thing i needed. Did u found the solution? this is not working nativescript-screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plugin http://plugins.nativescript.org/plugin/nativescript-screenshot which takes screenshot, try it out.